# Refining Script. Copy from Template to Exclude Specified Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
  function myFunction2() {
    // These variables are from your showing script.
    var templateSheetName = "Template";
    var sheetsToExclude = [templateSheetName, 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2'];
    var ranges = ['C12:C35', 'C5:C6', 'G16:G19', 'G4'];

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ssId = ss.getId();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets().filter(s => !sheetsToExclude.includes(s.getSheetName()));
    var formulas = ranges.map(r => ss.getSheetByName(templateSheetName).getRange(r).getFormulas());
    sheets.forEach(s => ranges.forEach((r, i) => s.getRange(r).setFormulas(formulas[i])));
  }
```

part of the code that need to be modified:

```
var sheetsToExclude = [templateSheetName, 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2']; var ranges = ['C12:C35', 'C5:C6', 'G16:G19', 'G4']; can these be edited to get the info from a range from a specific sheet?
```

if possible

can sheetsToExclude be values from Helper!A1:A8
can ranges be values from Helper1!B1:B4

```
Helper Sheet
    A               B              C
    1 Sheet1       C12:C35
    2 Sheet2       C5:C6
    3 Sheet3       G16:G19
    4 Sheet4       G4
    5 Sheet5       
    6 Sheet6       


    Goals: 
    1. Copy Template Formulas to Sheets Specified in Helper Sheet 
    2. Helper will contain the sheetnames in Column A. Just want to restrict it to be Helper!A1:A8 
    3. Helper will define the Range to be copied and where the data will be pasted (Same range) in Column B. Just want to restrict it to be Helper!B1:B4
```

Comment: From @Century Tuna's comment `@DCC I was pretty confused if you would want to include or exclude the sheets on range Helper!A1:A8 but i included both on my answer, feel free to test it out if it works.` in my answer, it seems that Century Tuna will answer to your question. In this case, I think that my answer is not useful. So I would like to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I would like to study more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this modification:**

```
 function myFunction2() {
    // These variables are from your showing script.
    var templateSheetName = "Template";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var helperSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Helper");
    var sheetsToExclude = helperSheet.getRange('A1:A8').getValues().flat();
    var ranges = helperSheet.getRange('B1:B4').getValues().flat().filter(rng => rng != '');
    
    var sheets = ss.getSheets().filter(s => !sheetsToExclude.includes(s.getSheetName()));
    var formulas = ranges.map(r => ss.getSheetByName(templateSheetName).getRange(r).getFormulas());
    sheets.forEach(s => ranges.forEach((r, i) => s.getRange(r).setFormulas(formulas[i])));
  }
```

**Changelogs:**

1. Added the "Helper" sheet so that you can set the sheets to exclude on `Helper!A1:A8` and the range to get the formulas on `Helper!B1:B4`.
2. Changed `var sheetsToExclude = [templateSheetName, 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2'];` to `var sheetsToExclude = helperSheet.getRange('A1:A8').getValues().flat();`
3. Changed `var ranges = ['C12:C35', 'C5:C6', 'G16:G19', 'G4'];` to `var ranges = helperSheet.getRange('B1:B4').getValues().flat().filter(rng => rng != '');`

**Explanation:**

How this works is that the modified `sheetsToExclude` gets the values from the Helper sheet using `getRange('A1:A8').getValues().flat().` using the `flat()` method to turn it into a 1d Array.

Using the same logic for the modified `ranges`, but had to use `filter()` method to filter out empty array elements.

**Modification part 2:**

```
 function myFunction2() {
    // These variables are from your showing script.
    var templateSheetName = "Template";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var helperSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Helper");
    var sheetsToInclude = helperSheet.getRange('A1:A8').getValues().flat();
    var ranges = helperSheet.getRange('B1:B4').getValues().flat().filter(rng => rng != '');
    
    var sheets = ss.getSheets().filter(s => sheetsToInclude.includes(s.getSheetName()));
    var formulas = ranges.map(r => ss.getSheetByName(templateSheetName).getRange(r).getFormulas());
    sheets.forEach(s => ranges.forEach((r, i) => s.getRange(r).setFormulas(formulas[i])));
  }
```

**Changelogs:**

1. Changed `var sheetsToExclude = helperSheet.getRange('A1:A8').getValues().flat();` to `var sheetsToInclude = helperSheet.getRange('A1:A8').getValues().flat();` because as per understanding, you would want to change this instead of excluding the sheets on the range, you would want to define where to copy the values instead.
2. Changed `var sheets = ss.getSheets().filter(s => !sheetsToExclude.includes(s.getSheetName()));` to `var sheets = ss.getSheets().filter(s => sheetsToInclude.includes(s.getSheetName()));`

**Explanation:**

This version, instead of excluding the sheets on range Helper!A1:A8 and defined ranges on Helper!B1:B4, this includes them to where the template will copy the formulas on the provided sheets defined on those ranges.

**References:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: I see I did not notice the exclude/include. yes. Helper!A1:A8 are the sheetnames to be selected to have the template formulas pasted. both script runs but does not copy the template.   I think script 2 is better. but it does not copy the formulas

Comment: Can we continue this through [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248723/room-for-diego-sanchez-and-dcc)?

Comment: second script worked. targeted ranges on my end was incorrect. thanks for pointing it out,